How to easily ship a CLI tool with Docker Compose?
I've created a dockerized environment with PHP, MariaDB and nginx (I am aware of the apache-php image at https://github.com/docker/awesome-compose but prefer nginx...).
It is available as a GitHub repo: https://github.com/Kehino/php-dev-docker
I did a bit of a hack to ship my custom version of composer (a PHP dependency management tool), although it means the "service" is started (then exits) each time I do docker compose up. This is convenient as I don't have to pass volume paths — although I'd be glad to also skip passing --user $(id -u):$(id -g) as part of this command:
docker compose run --rm --interactive --tty --user $(id -u):$(id -g) composer

Is there a more elegant way to do so?

Related resources:

Setting up PHP-FPM, Nginx, Mariadb on CentOs using docker (Stack Overflow)
PHP-FPM + Nginx docker-compose stack without duplicate volumes (Stack Overflow)
https://github.com/sitepoint-editors/sitepoint-docker-tutorial (similar dockerized environment)


Use a bash script.

Also composer already ships as a single executable PHAR artifact. Why does your custom composer need to be encapsulated further into a container?

Thanks for the answer, I feel stupid! I've updated the repo.

As of why a container for Composer, this is a recommend install method (https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#docker-image).
